# Dig Command on specific server gives different results than querying without specifying a NS

Tags: domain-name, dig, domain-name-system

I am currently experimenting with the `dig` command because I am having issues with my newly registered domain.
When I execute `dig @dns.dns1.de overminded.de` on one of my Debian servers, I am getting the following result:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> @dns.dns1.de overminded.de
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 30506
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;overminded.de.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
overminded.de.          86400   IN      A       92.222.252.3

;; Query time: 21 msec
;; SERVER: 2a02:2940:0:a0d1::246#53(2a02:2940:0:a0d1::246)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb  7 13:32:46 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 47
```

Everything seems fine here. We can see the A-Record being shown correctly. But when I do not specify a lookup-server (I used one of those shown as the authority servers in the command before), I get this output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> overminded.de
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 64219
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;overminded.de.                 IN      A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
de.                     1751    IN      SOA     f.nic.de. its.denic.de. 2015020745 7200 7200 3600000 7200

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 213.136.95.10#53(213.136.95.10)
;; WHEN: Sat Feb  7 13:32:39 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 83
```

As you can see, there is no ANSWER section there, and the status is also NXDOMAIN which means, afaik, that the domain is not yet registered.
For your information, I ordered the domain 2 days ago, and I am aware of having some waiting time until all DNS servers in the world know about my domain name. But I think 2 days are pretty long.

Do you have any ideas what might be the issue here? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I would bet on propagation at first glance but as you said 48H is "normally" the maximum amount of time.
Is your DNS Server handled on your debian or are you using your provider's one?

Comment: I am using the provider's DNS servers, because my own DNS server network is not set up yet.

Comment: Ok then, could you paste us your entry settings?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To take away your worries: The domain is registered to you.
Glue records are setup correctly.
The zone is responding correctly from the configured DNS servers.
It's hard to tell when it will be available everywhere - we'd need to know when your provider registered it.
And as you can see here, it is already resolving on some servers:
https://www.whatsmydns.net/#A/overminded.de

Just wait a bit more.

Comment: Cudo for the whatsmydns URL for tracking propagation!

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I can already access the domain when adding www, which is still somehow unusual that subdomains are reachable before the main name is ready. Anyways, I think you answered my question, so I marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: The reason for that is probably that your client (or upstream DNS server) is caching the NXDOMAIN response from earlier.